# Can an infrared port be added to a laptop?

Tags: remote-control, peripherals, infrared, ir

Recently I bought a used TV tuner which came with an MCE remote, but unfortunately not the receiver. I know that there are some receivers available on eBay (for a pretty penny), but I thought it would be cheaper/faster/easier to use it with an IR port. Sadly, not all laptops have an IR port.

A typical IRDA module seems like it might work, but laptops do not have IRDA headers on the motherboard, so some sort of USB dongle will be necessary.

I checked eBay, but it only seems to have actual MCE receivers, not generic USB-IR devices.

Is there a way to add an (IR remote compatible) infrared port to a laptop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found all kinds of USB IR devices online. Check [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001HBOJRQ). And here is one at [ByteRunner](http://www.byterunner.com/byterunner/product_name=Y-165/user-id=/password=/exchange=/exact_match=exact).

Comment: Yes I know; there are remotes/receivers on eBay too. I am not asking about a remote receiver, I am asking about an infrared port. I'm trying to find out if there is a way to add a generic, IRDA type of IR port to a laptop. Some people use them to sync data between a system and a phone, or game device, etc. The Amazon link is not applicable to this question, but the ByteRunner one does seem to be. (It's more expensive than I'd like since I would mostly only be using it for the remote for now, but at least they *do* exist.) (I'm wondering if it's possible to build-your-own.)